# c++ implementation of quadratic equation, throws an error when implemented on a school testing website

Tags: visual-c++, equation

I am trying to solve a very simple task tested by my univeristy's code checker. The code is about a c++ implementation of the equation of the quadratic equation. The code won't work for all cases, I am supplying my code, and if there is some comment, hint, please help me with it.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int a, b, c, delta;
    double x1, x2, x;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    delta = ((b*b) - (4 * a * c));
    if (a == 0) {
        if (b != 0) {
            x = (-(c*1.0) / (b));
            cout << 1 << " " << x;
        }
        else
            cout << "-1";
    }
    else
        if (delta > 0)
        {
            x1 = ((-(b + sqrt(delta))*1.0) / (2 * a));
            x2 = ((-(b - sqrt(delta))*1.0) / (2 * a));
            cout << 2 << " " << x1 << " " << x2;
        }
        else if (delta == 0)
        {
            x = (-(b*1.0) / (2 * a));
            cout << 1 << " " << x;
        }
        else
            cout << "-1";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All your variables are `int`. It would appear unlikely that all results and all intermediate values happen to be whole numbers.

Comment: I have edited the code for that matter before your comment and still didn't work.

Comment: *The code won't work for all issues* isn't a useful problem description. How do we reproduce those *issues*? When you step through the code in the debugger, where specifically is your code failing to produce the results you'd expect?

Comment: @KenWhite, here is the thing, the checker tests the code without showing test cases, I tried all cases I able to think of, it passed, though in the checker's mind, it still haven't captured something.

Comment: Then you need to work through some input yourself to figure out a set of data that makes it fail. We're not going to do that for you.

Comment: @KenWhite, yeah, I tried everything i could, works like magic!

Comment: Your code claims no solution for `a=0`, but an equation `b*x+c=0` does generally have one solution.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, yes I got it before the comment, but thanks, though, there is still a situation, when a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, then I don't know what to output, because the R is the set of solution, the problem description didn't state such condition for output. In any case, thanks.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik even though I implemented it, it's still not working for all test cases, can you please see what might be missing. Note, a=0, b=0, c=0, the problem should output -1.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, can you please take a look again?