# Decimal to binary implementation can't fully work on my university's checker. What can be the problem or the hint

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

I am trying to solve a very simple task tested by my univeristy's code checker. The code is about a c++ implementation of decimal to binary algorithm. The code won't work for all cases, I am supplying my code, and if there is some comment, hint, please help me with it.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int a, rem;
    int i = 0;
    int b[5];//log_2(16)+1
    cin >> a;
    if (a < 17)
    {   
        while (a)
        {
            rem = a % 2;
            b[i++] = rem;
            a /= 2;
        }
        for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--)//i = i-1 because i 5.
        {
            cout << b[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the data for the cases that don't work.

Comment: @RichardCritten the checker don't provide test cases for students

Comment: Well at least provide your test data and expected results - save everyone some time.

Comment: @RichardCritten actually, the program only asks for integers up to 16, so I did it for all of them it works just fine.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?  Convert one number?  Convert all of the numbers in the file?  How is it supposed to handle 0, or negative values.  If the value is greater than 16, what should it do?  I can tell you what it's doing for these situations now, but we have no clue what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, the imput is specified to be an integer a<17. I have no idea whether 0 this should be included.

Comment: Can you please comment on this recently asked question by mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960792/c-implementation-of-second-degree-equation-of-one-unknown-variable-throws-an

Answer (score 1):

This code expects integer input in [1, 16], as you can assume from this comment "log_2(16)+1". It produces the *correct result* for all 16 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you had given us some concrete example of where it does and does not work.

At first sight everything looks fine to me, except for a=0 (you could put a do-while instead of a while), and except for the fact that you used signed variables for a code which can't handle a sign.